# Moverse por los campos de un registro en C/C++ sin usar su nombre

Tags: c++

¿Es posible moverse por los campos de un registro en C/C++ sin conocer su nombre ni tampoco el tamaño que ocupan estos en memoria? es decir, supongamos que tenemos:

```
struct Ejemplo{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    ...
    int z;

};
struct Ejemplo var;
```

Ahora mismo si yo quiero asignar un valor a cada campo debo hacerlo campo a campo de la forma:

```
var.a = 1;
var.b = 2;
...
var.z = N;
```

Yo estoy interesado en hace algo del tipo:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    var.algo = i;
}
```

¿Es esto posible? ¿No me vale la opción de asignar un puntero a var e ir desplazándote de 4 en 4 bytes? Dado que en el ejemplo real no todos los campos son `int` algunos pueden ocupar más o menos bytes.

Comment: No, no es posible hacer eso. Seguramente terminaras haciendo violación de memoria si intentas hacer algo parecido a lo que propones, ya que no conoces como está formada la struct y terminarás escribiendo fuera de sus límites. Sin embargo lo que estás preguntando es bastante extraño, no entiendo por que necesitarias algo así. Te sugiero que nos cuentes cual es tu ejemplo real y seguramente haya otra forma de resolverlo

Comment: No existe ningún lenguaje llamado C/C++, la respuesta es diferente para C y para C++ que son lenguajes diferentes.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Necesito hacer un parseo de un registro de BBDD a una estructura con campos de diferentes tipos. La API de la BBDD me va dando el valor de cada campo por cada invocación, por lo que con un simple bucle iterando hasta el último campo podría implementarlo siempre y cuando me pudiese mover por la estructura sin conocer el nombre de los campos ni el tamaño de éstos. Estamos hablando de estructuras con 20-25 campos y cerca de 100 tablas.

Answer (score 2):

Tu mismo te estás respondiendo. Sin usar ningún artificio no es posible lo que pides.

Por un lado tienes que pensar que los datos pueden estar *alineados* o no. La alineación es una característica que hace que cada campo de la estructura se hubique al inicio de un registro de memoria.

Un ejemplo meramente ilustrativo. Suponiendo la siguiente estructura:

```
struct test
{
  unsigned a : 3; // campo de 3 bits
  unsigned b : 6; // campo de 5 bits
  unsigned c : 1; // campo de 1 bit
};
```

Su estructura en la memoria podría lucir así:

```
             | 8 bits | 8 bits | 8 bits | 8 bits |
Alineado:     aaa      bbbbbb   c
No alineado:  aaabbbbb bc
```

Como ves, si los registros no están alineados se puede dar el caso de que un campo involucre varios registros, lo que complica las operaciones de lectura y escritura.

Que los datos puedan estar o no alineados complica el proceso de saltar de un registro al siguiente, ya que puede no ser obvio conocer el incremento a aplicar en cada caso.

Por otro lado, tu mismo comentas que cada campo puede ser de un tipo diferente. Para realizar los saltos tendrías que tener en cuenta esa circunstancia so pena de saltar a una posición de memoria incorrecta.

Ahora bien, mediante determinados artificios se pueden solventar estos problemas. La pega es que tendrás que mantener más código. Por ejemplo puedes usar [BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html) si estás trabajando con **C++**:

```
struct Ejemplo{
    int a;
    float b;
    double c;
    std::string d;
};

// Mapeamos la estructura
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Ejemplo,
    (int, a)
    (float, b)
    (double, c)
    (std::string, d)
)

// Función que será llamada para cada miembro
template<class T>
void ImprimirValor(T& param)
{
  std::cout << param << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  Ejemplo ejemplo = { 1, 2.0, 3.0, "test" };
  boost::fusion::for_each(ejemplo,ImprimirValor);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. En mi caso los campos si están alineados. Lo que necesito hacer es un parseo de un registro de BBDD a una estructura con campos de diferentes tipos. La API de la BBDD me va dando el valor de cada campo por cada invocación, por lo que con un simple bucle iterando hasta el último campo podría implementarlo siempre y cuando me pudiese mover por la estructura sin conocer el nombre de los campos ni el tamaño de éstos. Estamos hablando de estructuras con 20-25 campos y cerca de 100 tablas.

Comment: @Eferion, una pregunta. ¿boost::fusion te permite generar dinámicamente los campos? ¿O solo funciona con tipos estáticos? Estoy viendo la documentación y me da la sensación que solo permite tipos estáticos.

Comment: Efectivamente. Solo campos estáticos. Todo tiene que ser conocido en tiempo de compilación. C++ no tiene ninguna capa de metadatos que te permita conocer el diseño de una estructura así por las buenas.

Comment: Me lo imaginaba. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

**Editado**

En los comentarios:

> trabajo con una función que me devuelve el valor de un campo y cada vez que se invoca me devuelve el valor del siguiente campo de ese registro

Según entiendo, la función de la que hablas trabaja de manera secuencial, en ese caso se puede *apañar* una solución (que tampoco es sencilla). Empezaremos por guardar en la propia estructura punteros a los elementos que queremos asignar:

```
struct Ejemplo{
    char c;
    short s;
    int i;
    float f;
    double d;

    // Coleccion de elementos asignables de la estructura
    static constexpr auto data = std::make_tuple(
        &Ejemplo::c,
        &Ejemplo::s,
        &Ejemplo::i,
        &Ejemplo::f,
        &Ejemplo::d
    );
};
```

Después usamos una función recursiva que vaya elemento a elemento de la colección y llame a una función para asignarles valor:

```
template <std::size_t ELEMENTOS>
void asigna(Ejemplo &ejemplo)
{
    constexpr auto data_size = std::tuple_size<decltype(Ejemplo::data)>::value;
    static_assert(ELEMENTOS <= data_size);
    auto miembro = std::get<data_size - ELEMENTOS>(Ejemplo::data);
    ejemplo.*miembro = funcion_que_me_devuelve_el_valor_de_un_campo();
    asigna<ELEMENTOS - 1>(ejemplo);
}

// Funcion vacia que rompe la recursion
template <>
void asigna<0u>(Ejemplo &) {}
```

Con esta aproximación puedes asignar los valores de `Ejemplo` secuencialmente con esta llamada:

```
Ejemplo var;
asigna<5u>(var);
```

Si tienes la posibilidad de compilar en C++17 la solución es ligeramente más interesante:

```
template <std::size_t ELEMENTOS, typename FUNCION>
void asigna(Ejemplo &ejemplo, [[maybe_unused]] FUNCION funcion)
{
    if constexpr (ELEMENTOS)
    {
        constexpr auto data_size = std::tuple_size<decltype(Ejemplo::data)>::value;
        static_assert(ELEMENTOS <= data_size);
        auto miembro = std::get<data_size - ELEMENTOS>(Ejemplo::data);
        ejemplo.*miembro = funcion();
        asigna<ELEMENTOS - 1>(ejemplo, funcion);
    }
}
```

Te ahorras la función vacía para romper la recursión al usar `if constexpr` y podemos añadir la función que devuelve el valor del siguiente campo como parámetro... cosa que no podíamos antes pues las funciones plantillas no se pueden especializar, con esta nueva aproximación en C++17 la llamada sería:

```
Ejemplo var;
asigna<5u>(var, funcion_que_me_devuelve_el_valor_de_un_campo);
```

Puedes ver el código [[funcionando aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/c6QjWly1rOD18td8).

**Respuesta original**

> Yo estoy interesado en hace algo del tipo:
>
> ```
> for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
>     var.algo = i;
> }
> ```

Esto es posible hacerlo (pero no es nada práctico) mediante punteros a miembro:

```
struct Ejemplo{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int z;

    using puntero_a_miembro = int Ejemplo::*;
    constexpr static puntero_a_miembro datos[5]{
        &Ejemplo::a,
        &Ejemplo::b,
        &Ejemplo::c,
        &Ejemplo::d,
        &Ejemplo::z
    };
};
```

Guardamos en `Ejemplo::datos`<sup>1</sup> la posición en `Ejemplo` de cada uno de sus miembros para después asignarlos usando un bucle:

```
Ejemplo var;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    var.*Ejemplo::datos[i] = i;
}
```

No es práctico porque:

- La sintaxis es confusa.
- Requiere mantener manualmente el arreglo `Ejemplo::datos`: Si se añaden nuevos datos a la estructura, necesitamos añadirlos al arreglo.
- No es válido con tipos diferentes dentro de la estructura: Los punteros de `Ejemplo::datos` son enteros (`int`) pertenecientes a `Ejemplo`; si en lugar de enteros fuesen otros datos se necesitaría otro puntero.

Si al final, todos los datos van a ser del mismo tipo ¿por qué no usar un arreglo interno?:

```
struct Ejemplo{
    int datos[5]{};
} var;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    var.datos[i] = i;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Al ser un miembro estático, no aumenta el tamaño de la estructura.

Comment: Gracías por la respuesta. En mi caso las estructuras tienen campos de distinto tipo, por lo que tener un array en este caso no me vale (de hecho alguno de los campos son arrays de enteros).

Comment: @EnriDuran Unas preguntas adicionales: ¿qué lenguaje estás usando C o C++? ¿por qué dices que "no conoces el nombre del campo"? ¿acaso lees datos de una Base de Datos con columnas anónimas?

Comment: Estoy usando C++. El nombre de los campos sí que los conozco.  Respecto a la BBDD, trabajo con una función que me devuelve el valor de un campo y cada vez que se invoca me devuelve el valor del siguiente campo de ese registro, así hasta el último campo. Entonces la idea sería ir llamando a esta función de forma sucesiva e ir cambiando de campo sin tener que estar poniendo el nombre. Trabajo con tablas 100 que pueden tener 20-30 campos. Pero tal y como suponía esto no se puede hacer en C o C++

Comment: Excelente explicación!!!